# Careers location confusion when entering Washington as a state

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On the careers page, I entered a new location for my "Willing to Locate" section.  Since my old one said "Oregon, United States", I typed in "Washington, United States" for the new location.  This was immediately changed to "Washington, DC. United States".  My attempts to remove the incorrect part was ignored when I tabbed out as it put the DC right back in.  After I changed it to "Washington State, United States" did it change back to my original typing of "Washington, United States"

Comment: Tr "WA, United States" as a possibly workaround. Not that it makes this issue less of a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We’ve hard-coded an exception for this case. Enter the location as either “Washington State” or simply “WA”, and it should resolve correctly.

Comment: Why wouldn't you include "Washington" in your list of exceptions?  I don't think anyone from DC will accidentally forget the 'DC' part...

Comment: @KevinVermeer Well, I think people meaning to type DC will accidentally forget from time to time, but it's still their own fault if/when they do.

Comment: The number of people who want "Washington DC" and forget the DC will surely be a lot less than those who want "Washington State" and don't know they should enter "State".

Comment: Neither of the workarounds work anymore.  They all shortcut back to "Washington, DC, United States".