# SO Careers profile: I can't be "willing to relocate to" Washington (the state) - automatically changes to the city (in D.C.)

Tags: bug, jobs, regression

Any attempt to use the word "Washington" results in "Washington, DC, United States."

Attempted values: "WA, United States"; "Washington State, United States"; "Washington, US"; "Washington, United States"; "WA, US"; "Washington".

As far as I can tell, there is no input that can be provided that results in "Washington, United States," meaning it's impossible to use that specific state as a relocation option. As far as I can tell, all other states select properly.

I have seen several older questions about this, but they all have been marked resolved (status-completed) and already have comments (as old as February 2015) indicating that this bug is in regression even though it was solved in the past. There are no responses to those comments so I'm opening a new question for the regression.

Original bug report from 2012: [Careers location confusion when entering Washington as a state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134416/careers-location-confusion-when-entering-washington-as-a-state)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting this problem. In a nutshell, the problem is this:

- The user enters "WA" or "Washington State" (the two workarounds documented in [Careers location confusion when entering Washington as a state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134416/careers-location-confusion-when-entering-washington-as-a-state))
- When leaving the text box, the entered value is sent to the server for validation and replaced with the "friendly name". In the case of the two workarounds, the friendly name is "Washington, United States".
- The user clicks "Save" to persist their changes to relocation locations.
- The entered locations are sent to the server to be saved. The same validation process is done, converting "Washington, United States" into "Washington, DC, United States". Whoops.

There are likely other cases beyond Washington State. We are still debating what to do about this as the process described above is generally good. I (or someone else on the dev team) will update once we have a resolution.

Comment: Hey, Jason! Thanks for the explanation. My first instinct is that the "friendly name" should come from the server with a unique identifier that, when saved, will be sent back to the server to get the correct location. Maybe there's another reason you're not doing it that way that I haven't thought of :) I'll be keeping my eye out for an update so I can modify my profile.

Comment: Additionally, without the unique identifier, there are a lot of potential name collisions, considering the number of cities in the world that you most likely support! I imagine there are other collisions that haven't been reported.

Comment: Is this fixed yet?